# Serial vs int schema data type options

Tags: 7, database

When should serial be chosen over an int when choosing a data type for a table column? Are they separated out for indicating a difference in the data types. If so what type of data should be stored as serial and as int?

Examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Serial is used for auto-increment column of the table, e.g. for node table nid has a serial data type and int can be any number based on size provided.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if that was the case. So the auto increment is implicit? Is there any documentation I can look at in regards to this. From the searching I was doing I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serial is used for auto-increment column of the table(so here auto increment is implicit), e.g. for node table nid has a serial data type and int can be any number based on size provided.

> '**type**': The generic datatype: 'varchar', 'char', 'int', 'serial',
>   'float', 'numeric', 'text', 'blob' or 'datetime'. The types map to the
>   underlying database engine specific datatypes. Use 'serial' for auto
>   incrementing fields.

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/schema-api/schema-reference

Comment: Great, thank you for creating an answer for this. Much appreciated!

Comment: Is it required to use the `serial` type if we have an integer field that is the primary key? For example, I'm creating a custom table that will be indexed by the node ID, but with existing node ID's, not any new ones I create.

Comment: Its not required.